# A PHP math expression generator?

Tags: php, math

I'm looking for a plugin or function or whatever that can take

```
-sin 3t + xy' - (3t^2 - 5)/(18t) = 21
```

(negative sine of 3t plus x times y prime minus the quotient of the difference of 3 times t squared and 5 and 18t equals 21)

or

```
lim (x -> 0^-) ((3x+8)/x) = +inf
```

(the limit as x approaches 0 from the left of the quotient of the sum of 3x and 8 and x is positive infinity)

and generate an image that looks like a mathematical expression or equation. I have found another plugin that uses LaTeX but this seems needlessly complicated. I've seen simpler math expression generators; for example, I do my math homework online by plugging in operations similar to these and it formats the results correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: So you want to re-invent Mathematica or Maple?

Comment: @Marc and his upvoters: He doesn't want to evaluate the expression, he wants to render it as a nice image

Comment: @gd1: yes, and that's what mathematic/maple are for, basically... turning numbers and number-generators into pretty pictures.

Comment: Hell no. They are for doing math stuff. For pretty pictures you use typesetting systems like LaTeX or, if you're lazy, WYSIWYG editors like Microsoft Word and shit like that

Comment: You should use LaTeX. That doesn't sound needlessly complicated. It handles all layout details for you, and does a very good job of it. Also, you seem to have found code that already does the work for you. (BTW: This is how MediaWiki does it, for example)

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help. See, the reason I don't want LaTeX is because it's more difficult. The website I'm trying to implement this on will be geared towards high school students and online math tutoring. delim{[}{x}{]} seems a bit hard for a mathematically challenged student to type, compared to abs(x). Microsoft Word has an excellent plugin for this actually, a Mathematics add-in or something. And WeBWorK is an ancient system we use for my calc class in college that renders quite well: http://webwork.maa.org/wiki/Available_Functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want something to render a nice image for a math formula.

I've googled "php formula render" for you and found, so far, this:
http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3612-PHP-Render-mathematical-formulas-as-images.html
Check it out :)

And this: http://www.xm1math.net/phpmathpublisher/
which looks fine. The language (see [this guide](http://www.xm1math.net/phpmathpublisher/doc/help.html)) doesn't seem to be outstandingly simple but it is fairly easy I think.

This other stuff seems not in PHP; but you can try to figure out how it works: http://www.algebra.com/services/rendering/
Seems like you can just use the website itself to render the formulas. It's an outsourced service. If you plan to use it, please have a look at the terms of usage.

Hope it helps, man...

Comment: Actually, looking into that guide you linked to, it isn't so scary after all. Thanks, I am going to reconsider it. Delimiters seem to be unnecessarily complex, but that's acceptable. This is the first site I came across and I instinctively didn't like it, but I just needed to give it more of a chance.

Comment: Just one question: how do you type a left-hand limit? lim{3^-}{18/x} only renders "lim", but lim{3^x}{18/x} works correctly.