# PHP Change Formula to Image Formula

Tags: php

i have simple formula in PHP like this

```
<?php
$r = ((($vector[$i][0] - $c1[0]) ** 2) + (($vector[$i][1] - $c1[1]) ** 2)) / 2
?>
```

I want to change that variable formula to image formula like this one

[image: image formula]

is it possible to make it happen in php?

Thanks

Comment: what is an image formula. You mean you want to generate an image like you posted from an actual php equation?

Comment: Would this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/7614234/1772933

Comment: yes, sorry for my bad english, i want to change php equation into an image like the example I made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those kinds of mathematical formulas, there is a library called `MathJax`, use that library, storing your formula in the database, and also displaying your formula.
For converting and storing that kind of formula there is software by the name of `MathType`.

FMI please visit the below links:

https://www.mathjax.org/

http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/

https://readthedocs.org/projects/mathjax/downloads/pdf/latest/

**MathType:**

https://www.wiris.com/en/mathtype/